# Android Google Fitness API for steps

Tags: android, google-api, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I have a service in my android app that i use for step counting. I fitness and history api for getting the daily and weekly steps. Everything was working correctly until suddenly the number of steps is always 0! The app seems to connect to fitness api using the above code

```
private void buildFitnessClient() {
    mGoogleApiFitnessClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ_WRITE))
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ_WRITE))
            .addConnectionCallbacks(
                    new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Google Fit connected.");
                            mTryingToConnect = false;
                            Log.d(TAG, "Notifying the UI that we're connected.");
                            notifyUiFitConnected();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                            mTryingToConnect = false;
                            if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Google Fit Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.");
                            } else if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Google Fit Connection lost.  Reason: Service Disconnected");
                            }
                        }
                    }
            )
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(
                    new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                        // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                            mTryingToConnect = false;
                            notifyUiFailedConnection(result);
                        }
                    }
            )
            .build();
}
```

while in order to retrieve the daily steps i use this function

```
private void getStepsToday() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();

    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    cal.setTime(now);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    DebugLogger.debug("Value of startTime = "+startTime+" - endTime = "+endTime);
    DebugLogger.debug("Test for getting steps "+getStepsCount(startTime,endTime));

    final DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .read(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();

    DataReadResult dataReadResult = Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mGoogleApiFitnessClient, readRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    DataSet stepData = dataReadResult.getDataSet(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA);


    int totalSteps = 0;
    DebugLogger.debug("GetStepsToday - Size in for loop "+stepData.getDataPoints().size());
    for (DataPoint dp : stepData.getDataPoints()) {
        for(Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
            int steps = dp.getValue(field).asInt();
            DebugLogger.debug("GoogleFit Service - debugging - steps count "+steps);
            totalSteps += steps;
        }
    }
    publishTodaysStepData(totalSteps, getGoalStep(goalEnabledDate));
}
```

As i mentioned everything was working ok but suddenly stepData.getDataPoints() size is always 0 returning me 0 steps. I created new Oath key for my debug and release keystore, i even changed my apps package name and recreated a project in Android API console but nothing. Is there anything i should change in the permissions or something? Do i need to declare my key anywhere in my app?

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of Google Play services on your device and ensure that you have the latest client library for Google Play services on your development host.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
...

dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:9.0.1'
}
```

- Open the Android SDK Manager.
- Under Extras, find Google Play services and Google Repository.
- If the status for these packages is different than Installed, select them both and click Install Packages.

Also, check in the Google Developers Console if the [APIs](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history) and [Auth](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/authorization) being set.